# ./a.out: Permission denied

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I've written a simple hello-world program in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   /* my first program in C */
   printf("Hello, World! \n");

   return 0;
}
```

I run `gcc main.c`, and this finishes with no errors or warnings. 
I've tried `chmod a+x a.out` and `chmod 755 a.out`. This is on my hard drive, which means it's not a `noexec` file system.
`ls -l a.out` gives me this:
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 keith keith 13932 Feb 15 13:20 a.out`
And yet, `./a.out` gives me: `bash: ./a.out: Permission denied` 
I've tried with and without sudo, and neither one works. Any help is appreciated.
EDIT:

```
file ./a.out gives: ./a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
ldd ./a.out gives: ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `./a.out'
        not a dynamic executable // 
LD_DEBUG=all ./a.out gives: bash: ./a.out: Permission denied
uname -a gives: Linux localhost 3.8.11 #1 SMP Sun Jul 14 00:09:57 PDT 2019 armv7l ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l) SAMSUNG EXYNOS5 (Flattened Device Tree) GNU/Linux
gcc -v gives: Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/armv7l-cros-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: armv7l-cros-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr/local --libdir=/usr/local/lib --build=armv7l-cros-linux-gnueabihf --host=armv7l-cros-linux-gnueabihf --target=armv7l-cros-linux-gnueabihf --enable-checking=release --disable-multilib --enable-threads=posix --disable-bootstrap --disable-werror --disable-libmpx --enable-static --enable-shared --program-suffix=-8.3.0 --with-arch=armv7-a --with-tune=cortex-a15 --with-fpu=neon --with-float=hard
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.0 (GCC)
```

Comment: Could you post the output of: `file ./a.out`? `ldd ./a.out`? `LD_DEBUG=all ./a.out`? `This is on my hard drive, which means it's not a noexec` - well, I do not think it means that, so just to be sure then, what is the output of `findmnt -T ./a.out`?

Comment: Please edit your question and please kindly post the info in the question. Comments are bad for multiple lines of output. `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3` - are you on arm? What is the output of `uname -a` and `gcc -v`? The `warning: you do not have execution permission` looks like you really don't have execution permissions.

Comment: @KamilCuk Added this information. Yes, I'm on a chromebook. Trust me, I'd use a better device if I had access to one.

Comment: I can only reproduce on a `noexec` filesystem. It should work - if the file really has `-rwxr-xr-x` then it should be executable. I suspected you were unconsciously crosscompiling, but gcc is arm7v and system is ARMv7, so not. So, what does `findmnt -T ./a.out` or `(until findmnt . ; do cd .. ; done)` output?

Comment: Turns out my Chromebook put it on some odd, seperate filesystem - thank you for the help @KamilCuk. I'll remount without noexec

Comment: @kel5isgod please make it an answer and add the necessary keywords (chromebook etc) into your question!